# Suppressing other canvas items from reacting to event

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a rectangle on a canvas listening for  events, with a callback function "A".

The blank space in the canvas is also listening to  events with a callback function "B".

When the I right-click on the rectangle, both "A" and "B" are executed. I understand why this happens (the rectangle is on the canvas).

The behavior I want to create is execution of "A" only when I right-click on the rectangle.
How can I stop the empty canvas area from reacting to the event?

See the code below as an example of the behavior I currently have.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(master=window)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
canvas.bind('<Button-3>', lambda event: print('canvas right click'))

rectangle_id = canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 300, 300, fill='red')
canvas.tag_bind(rectangle_id, '<Button-3>', lambda event: print('rectangle right click'))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @TheLizzard: that won't work since one binding is on a widget and one is on a tag. The two are handled separately.

Comment: @BryanOakley Oh my bad. Didn't know that. I assumed that the tag bindings would work the same way as widget bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into `tkinter` that does this. In fact, the `Canvas` [documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M37) specifically calls this out:

> If bindings have been created for a canvas window using the `bind` command, then they are invoked in addition to bindings created for the canvas's items using the `bind` widget command. The bindings for items will be invoked before any of the bindings for the window as a whole.

One workaround is to have your tag binding set some sort of flag to tell the canvas binding not to do any work.

Example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

do_right_click = True

def canvas_right_click(event):
    global do_right_click
    if do_right_click:
        print("canvas right click")
    do_right_click = True

def element_right_click(event):
    global do_right_click
    do_right_click = False  # prevent canvas from processing this event
    print("rectangle right click")

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(master=window)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
canvas.bind('<Button-3>', canvas_right_click)

rectangle_id = canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 300, 300, fill='red')
canvas.tag_bind(rectangle_id, '<Button-3>', element_right_click)

window.mainloop()
```